# Google Analytics Reporting api v3 to get data using PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a service account to grab data e.g **pageviews**, **users**, **bounce rate**, etc from Google Analytics. I've set up permission on my developer email address to access my **7** property data.

> Out of 7, I am able to grab data from 5 properties/sites but other 2
>   are not working

Although both account have access permission on **Google Analytics Administration › User Management**. I am using `Google Analytics V3` of PHP. Below is my used code given partially.

```
$account_id = 'ga:343434334'; // my view id goes here

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);

// seproate additional scopes with a comma
$scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";

$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $Email_address,
    array($scopes),
    $key
);

$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}

$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);


 // get page threshold
        $optParams1 = array(
            'dimensions' => 'ga:pageDepth',
            'sort' => '-ga:users',
            'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=@inquiry',
            'max-results' => '1'
        );
$results1 = $service->data_ga->get($account_id, $start_date, $end_date, 'ga:users', $optParams1);
print '<pre>';
print_r(results1);
printt '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using a service account for authentication.  On the accounts that you are missing access to double check that you grant the service account access at the **ACCOUNT** level.  Meaning you added the user at the **ACCOUNT** level if you only added the service account at the web property or view level it wont work.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I had my permission on Account level. I got the issue actually I thought I am unable to get data from GA but the reason "I was filtering the metrics thats why it was empty actually" . Thanks :)